# JAXB JavaTypeAdapter Not Working

Tags: java, xml, oop, jaxb

I currently have the class State which contains a boolean and a DoublePair (my own class). The DoublePair class has two instance variables: x and y. When I try and marshal the file, I would have the entry <XY/> with no other information. After some googling, I was told to use an XmlJavaTypeAdapter but once I Unmarshall my file, I get 0.0 as opposed to the expected 1.0. (ultimately I'm trying to use the HueSDK and am using this as a model to debug. That is why I have a custom DoublePair class (the original models the one for the API)

My XML root element class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class XMLManager {

    private State state;

    public XMLManager() {

    }

    public XMLManager(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public static void writeFile(XMLManager manager) {
        File f = new File("src/data/dat.xml");
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLManager.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(manager, f);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static XMLManager readFile() {
        File f = new File("src/data/dat.xml");
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLManager.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

            return (XMLManager) unmarshaller.unmarshal(f);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File xml = new File("src/data/dat.xml");
        try {
            if(!xml.createNewFile()) {

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        XMLManager m = new XMLManager();
        State s = new State();
        s.setIsOn(true);
        DoublePair dp = new DoublePair(1, 1);
        s.setXY(dp);
        m.setState(s);
        XMLManager.writeFile(m);

        m = XMLManager.readFile();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.getState().getXY().getValue())); // returns [0.0, 0.0]
    }
}
```

My State class:

```
public class State {

    private boolean isOn;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyDoublePairAdapter.class)
    private DoublePair xy;

    public State() {

    }

    public State(boolean isOn, DoublePair xy) {
        this.isOn = isOn;
        this.xy = xy;
    }

    public void setIsOn(boolean isOn) {
        this.isOn = isOn;
    }

    public boolean getIsOn() {
        return isOn;
    }

    public void setXY(DoublePair xy) {
        this.xy = xy;
    }

    public DoublePair getXY() {
        return xy;
    }

}
```

My DoublePair class:

```
public class DoublePair {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public DoublePair() {

    }

    public DoublePair(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double[] getValue() {
        return new double[] {x, y};
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setValues(double[] values) {
        x = values[0];
        y = values[1];
    }

    public void setValue(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

My Custom DoublePair class (simplified version)

```
public class MyDoublePair {

    private double x,y;

    public MyDoublePair() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public MyDoublePair(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class MyDoublePairAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MyDoublePair, DoublePair> {

    @Override
    public MyDoublePair marshal(DoublePair val) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Marshal: " + val.getX()); // returns 1
        return new MyDoublePair(val.getX(), val.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public DoublePair unmarshal(MyDoublePair val) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Unmarshal: " + val.getX()); // returns 1
        return new DoublePair(val.getX(), val.getY());
    }

}
```

Here is the output of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xmlManager>
    <state>
        <xy>
            <x>1.0</x>
            <y>1.0</y>
        </xy>
        <isOn>true</isOn>
        <XY/>
    </state>
</xmlManager>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I only resort to asking questions online when I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past.
In your case you just need XMLManager, State and DoublePair classes only. All you need to do is annotate DoublePair variable inside State as

```
 @XmlElement
private DoublePair xy;
```

and, annotate x and y inside DoublePair class as:

```
@XmlElement
private double x;

@XmlElement
private double y;
```

This should work.

Comment: The issue with this is with the HueSDK I'm using, I can't modify the DoublePair class and add the XmlElement tag.